# Phone applications written in c++

Tags: java, android, c++, ios, objective-c

I have an application idea that I want to create and I want to create this app for both iOS-iphone and Android.

So I would like to ask for some advise!

Is it possible to create a full fledged ( IOS and ANDROID ) application in pure C++ ?

Is it smart to create an application in C++ for both ( IOS and ANDROID ) or is it better to write the application in ( Objective-C and Java ) for each devise target.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use C++ for (a large portion of) applications for both systems... but it's also possible to stab your eye with a fork (and possibly more pleasant).

Comment: Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Xamarin.](http://xamarin.com/) I believe that will do what you want. I haven't used it, but colleagues of mine have. They say by writing with Xamarin, they will accomplish about 75% of their code. But they will need to go in to each iOS and Android to work on specific code, usually for the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Both Android and iOS can handle c++, but the UI is programmed in their native languages. Obj-C for iOS and Java for Android.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use native APIs for anything, you can write your app in C++

Most people seem to think that the biggest downside is that you can't use the UI APIs for the platforms, but if your app has a simple interface, you can render and handle it in OpenGL. The biggest downside would be the lack of networking APIs imo.

As far as Android is concerned, writing your Model and Controller in C++ and then just doing the View part as Java code would be a pretty horrible - C++ may be 15-20% faster in execution, but constantly doing calls to the native layer would make your app slower overall due to the overhead.

It really depends on what your app needs to accomplish. I'm not familiar with cross-platform tools like Xamarin, but if you find something that generates Android Java and iOS Objective C which you can then edit however you like, that would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

IOS is written in objective-c whereas Android is written in Java. Although Android apps can use C/C++ as part of the NDK it wouldn't really be suitable, maybe not even possible for the entireity of the app to be written in C++. C++ in Java would only be used really in time critical parts of the app where you can't afford to have delays from overheads in Java such as the memory management/Garbage collection.

AS Binghammer pointed out, Xamarin could be used to create a cross platform Android/IOS app although this would be written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

[Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/) enables Objective-C apps to be run on both iOS and then rebuild for Android.

The advantage of Apportable over C# or C++ is support for much of the rich set of Objective-C API's that facilitate mobile device programming.